# Speech recognizer gets duplicated results in handler

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

This is my current code: 
(I will explain my issue after that)

```
Choices sList;
Grammar gr;
SpeechRecognitionEngine sRecognize = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

private void BtnStartLuister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sList = new Choices();
        sList.Add(new string[] { "hallo", "ik", "ben", "Ken", "zoek", "exit", "leeg", "stop", "add" });
        gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));
        BtnStartLuister.Enabled = false;
        BtnStopLuister.Enabled = true;
        try
        {
            //sRecognize.MaxAlternates = 0;
            sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            sRecognize.LoadGrammar(gr);
            sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
            sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            sRecognize.Recognize();
        }

        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    private void BtnStopLuister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sRecognize.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        BtnStartLuister.Enabled = true;
        BtnStopLuister.Enabled = false;
    }
    private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            case "exit": { Application.Exit(); break; }
            case "stop": { BtnStopLuister_Click(sender, e); break; }
            case "zoek": { btnZoek_Click(sender, e); break; }
            case "add": { VoegToeBtn_Click(sender, e); break; }
            case "leeg": { tbWoord.Clear(); break; }
            default: { tbWoord.Text = tbWoord.Text + e.Result.Text.ToString() + " "; break; }
        }
    }
```

So, if i click the 'BtnStartLuister', It will start listening to words which are in sList. Works great, and outputs them to tbWoord (A textbox in my form) IF the case is default.
Now the actual issue: If I press the button 'BtnStopLuister', it stops listening etc. If I press 'BtnStartLuister' again, and then say "Ken" for example, it outputs "Ken" **twice**. I tried debugging, and it seems that there are some Alternates which e.Result carries. Fine to me, but I don't want them to output to my textbox.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Any help will greatly be appreciated :)

(Btw, I'm pretty new to C# (& programming in general) & sorry if there are some variable names partly in Dutch)

Comment: `sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;` - you're subscribing to the event every time the `BtnStartLuister_Click` method runs. Unsubscribe in the stop button event handler.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you CodeCaster! Works like a charm now :) Just a stupid little mistake I made there haha.

Comment: Is it really necessary to downvote this question? I feel that this is a common mistake and there's no obvious, easy way for a new programmer to pick up on this mistake or even search for it to figure out on their own what's wrong.

Comment: @sab669 Thanks sab :) Saw the downvotes too and was like, ' well sorry for asking' lol. Glad it's fixed now however.

Comment: To see less downvotes you might name question properly, you need to be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What CodeCaster said in the comment:

```
sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
```

> you're subscribing to the event every time the BtnStartLuister_Click method runs. Unsubscribe in the stop button event handler."